# pass request parameter value to class function and return value in classic asp

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

I am 3 days new to classic asp after a few years of .NET.

I have a simple form (consisting of radio buttons) that collects information and saves it to the a database (think basic survey form).

I get the following error when submitting the form:

```
Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01a8'

Object required: ''

/project/surveypage.asp, line 83
```

I have the following code on the survey page (snippet)

```
<%
  Dim oConstants
  Set oConstants = new Constants

  Dim d1NumberOfFF

  d1NumberOfFF = oConstants.GetValue(Request.Form("d1NumberOfFF")) '<--- line 83
%>
```

And the following class (Constants.asp):

```
<%
Class Constants 

    '..........
    function GetValue(item)
        GetValue = 99
        If NOT IsEmpty(item) Then
            GetValue = item
        End if
    end function
End Class
 %>
```

It seems basic enough but is acting like the function doesn't exist or that I can't pass the Form value? Beginning to think I've been too babied by .NET

Comment: There must be something outside your code snippets causing the problem. I just stuck your class and survey page code into a test script and it works fine (and returns 99).

Comment: Adding a form that posts `d1NumberOfFF` as a different value works as expected too. If you expand on your code snippets I'll take another look for you.

Comment: @Polly ... I think this falls under rookie mistake. I abbreviated my code example too much, `Dim oConstants` is declared in a separate `<% %>`. Originally I went to reuse the `oConstants` by re-declaring right before trying to use the function on `d1NumberOfFF` but it gave me the error that `oConstants` was already defined so I deleted the "re-declare". I guess calling variables from different `<% %>` causes the reference to be lost but the variable kept?

Comment: Script blocks don't count as a scope on their own, no. If you `Dim` and set something in one block, it will be accessible from any subsequent one in the same script.

Comment: For example (not very readable on one line, but you get the idea): `<% Dim x %> <% x = 1 %> <%= x %>`

Comment: once I did `set oConstants = new Constants` in the second block everything started working again, it's weird

Comment: Perhaps you reassigned oConstants to something other than your class at some point? Scoping can be confusing in ASP classic until you get used to its quirks.

Answer (score 0):

You say you cant pass a querystring value, and you're using Request.Form("d1NumberOfFF") on line 83.

Request.Form only captures form variables (ie from a form using method="post"), Request.Querystring is the equivalent for a querystring value, or you could just use Request and it would collect either kind of variable